# python project euler 6 with any number

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with Project Euler #6. The question is as follows:

Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.

I'm trying to write my code in such a way that what is being asked in Euler(all numbers up to and including 100) can be substituted for any number you like (all numbers up to and including x). I decided that in order to do this, you would need 3 functions. Code is:

```
#the sumSquare function squares every number from 0 to number called 
#in the function and adds each term to a list. the function returns the sum
#of all numbers in this list

def sumSquare(num):
    list1 = []

    for i in range(num+1):
        x = i^2
        list1.append(x)
    return sum(list1)


#the squareSum function adds every whole number from 0 up to and including
#the number called in the function to list2. It returns the sum squared of  #every number in the list


def squareSum(num):
    list2 = []
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        list2.append(i)
    return (sum(list2) * sum(list2))

def ans(num):
    return squareSum(num) - sumSquare(num)



print ans(100)
```

My output is 2549748 but I'm reading online that the correct solution is 25164150. Does anyone see where I am going wrong. I am just learning to code so I may be missing something that would be easy to spot by someone more experienced. But as far as I can tell, the lists are being filled with what would be the appropriate numbers before they are summed.

Comment: Unreleated but range returns a list, so no need to iterate and add the value to a 2nd list.  `sum(range(1,num+1))` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
i^2
```

Is not a square in Python.  Use `i*i` or `i**2` for a square.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is anylanguage code. But with sintax error.
Really power in Python is ** 
So.

Python-style code looks like that one:

```
print(sum(range(1, 101))**2 - sum([i**2 for i in range(1, 101)]))
```

Thats why they love the Python (R)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the input. After thinking a bit more I realized just how overly convoluted this code was. I realized that if all three functions are taking the same variable to solve the problem, it can be simplified into one function that takes care of each step on its own. Came up with this solution which is obviously much more efficient:

```
import time


def ans(num):
    numSq = []
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        numSq.append(i**2)
    return ((sum(range(1, num+1))**2)-sum(numSq))

start_time = time.time()
print ans(100)
print "This program took {} seconds to execute.".\
format(time.time() - start_time)
```

Running the program you get:

```
25164150
This program took 0.00800013542175 seconds to execute.
```

Again, thanks for the input on my first post!

Answer (score 0):

```
def diffSum():
    sumSquares = 0
    squareSum = 0
    sumT = 0
    for i in range(1,101):
        sumSquares = sumSquares + (i * i)
    for i in range(1,101):
        sumT = sumT + i
    squareSum = sumT * sumT
    return squareSum - sumSquares

#sumsquares gets all the summation of the square numbers of the first 100 numbers
#sumT stores the summation of the first 100 numbers 
#squareSum squares the summation of the first 100 numbers 
#returns the difference between sumSquares and squareSum
```

Comment: please provide an explanation of your code to improve the quality of your answer